# Having trouble creating an instagram script to unfollow who I am following through selenium/python

Tags: python, selenium

I am practicing web parsing by scripting instagram. When I view my own profile and click on my following page. A dialog box appears with all the people that I am following with a button labelled "following" next to each name. No matter how I try to target and click this button, it never works I keep trying to target it to no success. I believe it is because there is no link attached to the button in the code that I am reading.

Instagram code:

```
<button class="sqdOP  L3NKy    _8A5w5    " type="button">Following</button>
```

Code I have used:

```
unfollow = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('following')
unfollow.click()

unfollow = driver.find_elements_by_text('Following')
unfollow.click
```

Comment: We’re probably going to need to see the rest of your program. Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right.
and it would not find element properly.
If you use find_elements not find_element, then you should use exactly where you want.

```
Why don't you use xpath instead of partial link?

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class='sqdOP  L3NKy    _8A5w5    ']').click()
```